# How can I get the underlying Socket from an httpclient connection?

Tags: java, sockets, apache-httpclient-4.x

This question is worded the same way as another question on SO ([HttpClient: how do I obtain the underlying socket from an existing connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741417/httpclient-how-do-i-obtain-the-underlying-socket-from-an-existing-connection)), but that question is actually about tunneling other protocols through HTTP(S) and thus the answer is quite a bit different.

What I'm trying to do is make an HTTPS connection, then find out the details of that connection. Java's `SSLSocket` class will give me what I need, but I need to be able to get a hold of the `Socket` itself in order to interrogate it.

Is there a way to get to the underlying `Socket`? httpclient/httpcore has become a maze of factories and private/protected implementations of things, so it's really difficult to poke-around the API to figure out how to actually get things once they have been configured.

Comment: What information are you looking for from the socket exactly? If `HttpClient` does not expose access to its `Socket` object, you could just use `(SSL)Socket` directly to implement HTTP(S) manually.

Comment: You cant. The only way to expose created sokets is to provide own socket factory and store references to created sockets by yourself

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm looking for the negotiated TLS protocol and cipher suite. I have limited those that *can* be negotiated, but I'd like to log those that were actually chosen for the conversation.

Comment: @Antoniossss you most certainly can use `(SSL)Socket` directly, even if you obtain it from a factory. There is nothing that says you must use `HttpClient` to implement HTTP(S). It is a convenience, not a requirement. If you understand how TCP and HTTP work, and have adequate skills in them, you can implement HTTP(S) directly in your own code without using `HttpClient` at all. I would not *recommend* it, but it is doable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Honestly, I really dislike `HttpClient` at this point. I tolerated it in some sample code for a service that we are using, but I'm about to throw it all out the window and re-implement the HTTP stuff myself. We have written our own HTTP clients for other services, and it's pretty trivial. We don't need 1000 classes and interfaces to handle HTTP POST and HTTP GET.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but u cant get it from the client - you cant get the socket that is created under the hood. So I think u missed the point here

Comment: @Antoniossss You can most certainly get the underlying socket, whether you are using HttpClient or not. @oleg's accepted answer has the code to prove it for HttpClient, and it's trivial to get access to the socket if you are implementing your own `SSLSocketFactory` -- just grab the socket as it's being created. But you are right: there is no `HttpURLConnection.getSocket` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a somewhat different technique, but @oleg got me on the right track. Here's my one-time code:

```java
HttpClientContext ctx = HttpClientContext.create();
HttpResponse response = getHttpClient().execute(method, ctx);

if(log.isDebugEnabled())
{
    ManagedHttpClientConnection connection = ctx.getConnection(ManagedHttpClientConnection.class);
    // Can be null if the response encloses no content
    if(null != connection)
    {
        Socket socket = connection.getSocket();
        if(socket instanceof SSLSocket)
        {
            SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket)socket;
            log.debug("Connected to " + getEndpointURL()
                      + " using " + sslSock.getSession().getProtocol()
                      + " and suite " + sslSock.getSession().getCipherSuite());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient intentionally makes it difficult to get hold of the underlying connection object and the socket it is bound to, primarily to ensure the connection state is consistent and persistent connections in the connection pool are safe to be re-used by another transaction.

However, one can get hold of the underlying connection from a response interceptor.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .addInterceptorLast(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void process(
                    final HttpResponse response,
                    final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.adapt(context);
                ManagedHttpClientConnection connection = clientContext.getConnection(ManagedHttpClientConnection.class);
                // Can be null if the response encloses no content
                if (connection != null) {
                    Socket socket = connection.getSocket();
                    System.out.println(socket);
                }

            }
        })
        .build();
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"))) {
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
```

Comment: Once you have the `Socket`, you can typecast it to `SSLSocket` and get its `SSLSession`, which can then tell you the negotiated SSL protocol and cipher suite that are being used.

Comment: I'm giving this a try right now. As I type the code, it occurs to me that this interceptor will likely fire for every response I get... so if I use HTTP keep-alive and the connection remains open, my interceptor will fire for each request and not just when the TLS handshake completes. I'll have to take that into account when writing the code to avoid logging the TLS info multiple times.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I know how to both cast a socket to `SSLSocket` and get the protocol parameters. I just didn't know how to fetch the socket itself.

Comment: Since I was only interested in the initial handshake, I adapted this code a bit. Instead of using an `HttpResponseInterceptor`, I created a new `HttpClientContext` and used it to make my first request (which is always an "authenticate" request, so always first). Everything inside of the `process` method is still applicable after that point.